# how to filter email address in log4j2 configuration in spring boot

Tags: regex, spring-boot, log4j2

I am trying to config the log4j2 in my spring boot app. I donot want to log the msg if there is some "Highly Sensitive", "Sensitive", and "Confidential" data in log like token, phone number, email which are dynamic and also some static words like firstname, lastname, Authorization like that.
Here below is my config

```
Configuration:
  status: info
  name: log4j2YAMLConfig
  ThresholdFilter:
    level: info
  # filter out "Highly Sensitive", "Sensitive", and "Confidential" data
  RegexFilter:
    regex: "(?si).*(Bearer|Authorization: Basic|X-Api-Key|X-Auth|Cookie|firstName|lastName|taxId|phone|email).*"
    onMatch: "DENY"
    onMismatch: "NEUTRAL"
    useRawMsg: true
  appenders:
    RollingFile:
      name: fileAppender
      fileName: "/app/logs/my-admin-web=${env:xxx}.log"
      filePattern: "/app/logs/my-admin-web-${env:xxx}-%i.log"
      bufferedIO: false
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "DateTime=%d{ISO8601}{GMT} Application=my-admin-web-${env:xxx} Thread=[%.30t] Logger=%c Type=%p RequestInfo=%X Message=%m%n"
      Policies:
        SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
          size: "1 MB"

  Loggers:
    Root:
      level: info
      AppenderRef:
        -
          ref: fileAppender
          level: debug
        -
          ref: fileAppender
          level: info
        -
          ref: fileAppender
          level: warn
        -
          ref: fileAppender
          level: error
    Logger:
      -
        name: com.home.www.abc.travel.admin.web.controllers.InvoiceController.successfulPayment
        additivity: false
        level: info
        AppenderRef:
          -
            ref: fileAppender
            level: debug
          -
            ref: fileAppender
            level: info
          -
            ref: fileAppender
            level: warn
          -
            ref: fileAppender
            level: error
```

I tried this

```
RegexFilter:
    regex: "(?si).*(Bearer|Authorization: Basic|X-Api-Key|X-Auth|Cookie|firstName|lastName|taxId|phone|email).*"
    onMatch: "DENY"
    onMismatch: "NEUTRAL"
    useRawMsg: true
```

But this will only filter out the words matched with regex if its there in log but not by the actual email address.

tried this one also didn't worked :(

```
regex: ".*^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$.*"
```

Comment: Do you have something like this in mind? https://regex101.com/r/2vSgj5/1/ (I've replaced your simplistic email pattern with the recommended version from here https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Comment: I just tried this got error while compiling the app.  
```found unknown escape character /(47) 
 in 'reader', line 8, column 123:
     ... |taxId|phone).*|[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'* ... ``` 

 it doesnot allow  \ in regex

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^\w+([.]\w+)*@\w+([.]\w+)+$
```

for example: (from [regex test web](https://regex101.com/))

[image]